# Convergence of random Borel probability measures with Wasserstein distance

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I have a couple of questions about proof of Lemma $19$, in page $958$ [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00440-017-0796-7).

Let $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite first absolute moment, equipped with Wasserstein distance

$$\mathcal{W(L_1,L_2)} = \sup_f \biggl|\int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathcal{L}_1 - \int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathcal{L}_2\biggr| $$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{L_1,L_2}$ are two Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ (Defined in page $937$).

Lemma $19$: Let $\mathcal{L}_n$ be a sequence of random elements of $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{L}_n$ be a uniformly integrable sequence of deterministic elements of $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$. If for every $f$, s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$,

$$\biggl|\int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathcal{L}_n - \int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathbb{L}_n\biggr|\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{P} 0$$

then $\mathcal{W}(\mathcal{L}_n,\mathbb{L}_n)\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{P} 0$

> Q$1$) If $\biggl|\int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathcal{L}_n - \int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathbb{L}_n\biggr|\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{P} 0$ for all Lipschitz continuous $f$, then wouldn't $\mathcal{W}(\mathcal{L}_n,\mathbb{L}_n) = \sup_f \biggl|\int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathcal{L}_n - \int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathbb{L}_n\biggr|\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{P} 0$ by definition of Wasserstein distance?

Proof: It is classical that convergence in $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$ can be tested on a certain countable family $\mathcal{F}$ of Lipschitz continuous functions, in the following sense:

$$\mathcal{W}(\mathbb{L}_n,\mathbb{L})\to 0 \iff \forall f\in \mathcal{F} \int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathbb{L}_n\to \int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mathbb{L} \tag{1}$$

One may take, for example, the function $x\to |x|$ together with functions $x\to \frac{1-e^{-\theta [x]_+}}{\theta}$ and $x\to \frac{1-e^{-\theta [x]_-}}{\theta}$ for all positive rational numbers $\theta$, since convergence in $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$ is equivalent to weak convergence and convergence of the first absolute moment.

> Q$2$) I understand that rational $\theta$ is chosen so as to get a countable family of functions but don't understand why convergence in $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$ is equivalent to weak convergence and convergence of the first absolute moment? By convergence in $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$, I guess they mean $(1)$ but isn't that a weaker condition than weak convergence as I thought weak convergence was $(1)$ for all Lipschitz continuous $f$? So why is convergence of first absolute moment needed? Thanks.

Comment: For both questions, pointwise and uniform convergence are different things. Convergence for each fixed $f$ is strictly weaker than convergence that is uniform over all Lipschitz $f$.

Comment: @RhysSteele I see, thanks.